# Problem with naming the variables of filtered data in ShinyApp

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, radio-button, dashboard

Hope you all are well. I'm facing a small problem with ShinyApps.
I have attached a picture of what i require.
I'm basically targeting **cyl** variable of **mtcars** data. If i press **4** from it, i require the filtered data having 4 along-with rest of variables having **four** attached to their names. 
Likewise if i press **4 and 6 together**, i require filtered data having 4 and 6 of *cyl* along with **four and six** attached to rest of variable names. 
The attached picture will make things easier to understand.
I'm attaching my codes as well.
Please guide me. Bundle of thanks in advance :)

[image]

```
data_table<-mtcars

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "variables", label = "Choose number(s):",
           choices =c("4","6", "8"),
           selected = c("4")),


DT::dataTableOutput("distable"))



server <- function(input, output){

thedata <- reactive({

if(input$variables != '0'){
  data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$variables,]
}

# 
# if(input$variables == '4'){
#   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "four","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
# }
# 
# if(input$variables == '6'){
#   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "six","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
# }
# 
# if(input$variables == '8'){
#   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "eight","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
# }
# 
# 


})


output$distable = DT::renderDataTable({

DT::datatable( filter = "top",  
             {   thedata() # Call reactive thedata()

                              })  

})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: for the 4 and 6 part, what if there are different rows for 4 and 6? The output cant be a `cbind` table in that as shown

Comment: Hi mate, for now we can assume that number of rows are same, we can do cbind as well. If possible could you pl update the codes. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
data_table<-mtcars
library(data.table)
repl <- list("4"="four","6"="six","8"="eight")

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "variables", label = "Choose number(s):",
                     choices =c("4","6", "8"),
                     selected = c("4")),


  DT::dataTableOutput("distable"))



server <- function(input, output){

  thedata <- reactive({

    if(input$variables != '0'){
      data_table<-data_table[data_table$cyl %in% input$variables,]
      colnames(data_table) <- gsub(paste( paste("_",sapply(repl, paste),sep=""),collapse="|"),"", colnames(data_table))
      cols <- colnames(data_table)
      suffix <- paste(paste("_", sapply(repl[input$variables],paste), sep=""),collapse="")
      setnames(data_table, old = cols[3:length(cols)], new = paste(cols[3:length(cols)], suffix, sep=""))

    }

    # 
    # if(input$variables == '4'){
    #   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "four","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
    # }
    # 
    # if(input$variables == '6'){
    #   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "six","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
    # }
    # 
    # if(input$variables == '8'){
    #   names(data_table)[3:11]<-paste( "eight","_" ,names(data_table)[3:11])
    # }
    # 
    # 


  })


  output$distable = DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable( filter = "top",  
                   {   thedata() # Call reactive thedata()

                   })  

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This will provide the suffix for what you want. For this `mtcars` example, the `cbind` part is not possible as there are varying length of rows for each filter, but this will give you a good start.

**Explanation**

We use

```
repl <- list("4"="four","6"="six","8"="eight")
```

for creating an initial lookup to map the `input$variables` to the suffix to be used.

After the actual filtering in `thedata` function, here is what happens -

```
colnames(data_table) <- gsub(paste( paste("_",sapply(repl, paste),sep=""),collapse="|"),"", colnames(data_table))
```

This is for resetting any previous renames that you might have done. So it will replace suffixes like `_four`, `_six` etc. so you can start over.

```
cols <- colnames(data_table)
  suffix <- paste(paste("_", sapply(repl[input$variables],paste), sep=""),collapse="")
```

`suffix` prepares the suffix which can correspond to `_four`, `_four_six` depending upon number of selections coming from `input$variables`

```
  setnames(data_table, old = cols[3:length(cols)], new = paste(cols[3:length(cols)], suffix, sep=""))
```

This part does the final replace with the suffixes with `setnames` from `data.table` library which helps replace a subset of column names in a R `df`.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, really appreciate the effort. But i actually want separate columns for 'four', 'six'  and 'eight'. Right now they are concatenating. Is it possible to achieve separate columns. Regards